# Delphi: How create a detached process independent from main application?

Tags: delphi

From my application i need to create a detached process independent from the main application. This means, if user close the main application, the new process still active. I don't need to wait for the output from the new process, then i can create a new process without wait for the response.

[image]

**The purpose is create a separate pipe for complete a long operation without waiting for the end and without terminate if the main application is terminated.**

Basically, this code see works.

```
uses ShellApi;

begin
  ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar('MyConsole.EXE'), PChar('MyParam'), '', SW_HIDE);
end;
```

however, i have a doubt, the process is spawned from a DLL loaded from the main application, and `ShellExecute` require a `HWND`, is appropriate spawning a new process from a DLL with `ShellExecute`?

*Thanks, and sorry for bad english!*

Comment: Use `CreateProcess` to create new processes, don't use `ShellExecute`. The window handle that is passed to `ShellExecute` is just used as the owner window for any dialogs shown, but there won't be any. The processes will not be connected in any way, Windows doesn't have the concept of parent/child process as *nix does. If both apps are console mode apps then they will share a console, but I don't think that's the case here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks david! i can CreateProcess without WaitForSingleObject and immediately CloseHandle?

Comment: Yes you can....

Comment: this is the answer of my question, thanks!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i have update the question with the solution. thanks a lot!

Comment: Please don't add an answer in the question. If you want to add an answer, do it as an answer. I reverted. However, your code doesn't perform error checking properly. If you posted it as an answer, I'd have to downvote it because of that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ok i have add an answer... where is the error checking error?

Answer (score -1):

I want share the solution made with `CreateProcess` (thanks to @DavidHeffernan).

`ShellExecute` is not appropriate for spawning a new process because the process is spawned from a DLL loaded from the main application, and `ShellExecute` require a `HWND`.

```
function RunProcess(ACommand: string): boolean;
var
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation;
begin
  UniqueString(ACommand); // CreateProcess requires writeable string for lpCommandLine arg

  FillChar(StartupInfo, SizeOf(StartupInfo), #0);

  StartupInfo.cb          := SizeOf(StartupInfo);
  StartupInfo.dwFlags     := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK;
  StartupInfo.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;

  Result := CreateProcess(nil, PChar(ACommand), nil, nil, False, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, StartupInfo, ProcessInfo);
  if Result then
  begin
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
  end;
end;

// ...

begin
  if not(RunProcess('MyConsoleApp.exe')) then
    raise Exception.Create('RunProcess failed');
end.
```

Comment: You don't test the return value of CreateProcess. Also you get a null terminated character string with `PChar(AFileName)` which avoids range errors if string is empty. Finally you need to use UniqueString to make the string writeable.

Comment: I think you first need to explain why ShellExecute is not appropriate for spawning a new process from a DLL. Otherwise I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have updated with PChar(ACommand), but i don't understand how use UniqueString and testing the the return value... sorry..

Comment: `ProcessInfo` is only guaranteed to be populated if `CreateProcess` returns true. 
And the lpCommandLine arg must be writeable, hence caling http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.UniqueString. I'll edit the answer for you.

Comment: Great! thanks a lot and sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. However the information you give is not correct. ShellExecute does not care and does not know if it is called from a dll or otherwise. Additionally ShellExecute does not require a window handle.